# Unable to start Guest OS on Virtual Machine as Kernel driver not installed

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I am using Virtual Box on Ubuntu Host machine and Windows 7 as Guest OS. I was able to run Windows before many times but recently after installing updates on my Ubuntu Box, it is showing error. Below is the screenshot of the error-
[image]

Below is the detail of the error-

```
The virtual machine 'Windows' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).


Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
MachineWrap
Interface: 
IMachine {f30138d4-e5ea-4b3a-8858-a059de4c93fd}
```

As per the suggestion, I tried running `sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup` on terminal, but it failed with following message-

```
ravi@Dell:~$ sudo /sbin/rcvboxdrv setup
Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Removing old VirtualBox pci kernel module ...done.
Removing old VirtualBox netadp kernel module ...done.
Removing old VirtualBox netflt kernel module ...done.
Removing old VirtualBox kernel module ...done.
Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules ...done.
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why)
```

The `dmesg` command is showing following information-

```
ravi@Dell:~$ dmesg|tail
[11128.973745] i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
[11130.401285] dell_laptop: Keyboard brightness level control not supported
[11195.330664] audit_printk_skb: 153 callbacks suppressed
[11195.330671] audit: type=1400 audit(1468644989.132:62): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=6051 comm="apparmor_parser"
[11195.330689] audit: type=1400 audit(1468644989.132:63): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=6051 comm="apparmor_parser"
[11195.331654] audit: type=1400 audit(1468644989.132:64): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=6051 comm="apparmor_parser"
[11854.988254] systemd-hostnamed[6528]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[16286.725959] capability: warning: `VirtualBox' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
[16893.539293] systemd-hostnamed[9073]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[17477.423820] systemd-hostnamed[11935]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
```

The virtual box log `/var/log/vbox-install.log` is displaying `Kernel configuration is invalid`. Please see the below error in log file-

```
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
    echo >&2;                           \
    echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
    echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
    echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
    echo >&2 ;                          \
    /bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*
```

I tried `sudo make oldconfig && make prepare` but it also failed. Below is the error message-

```
ravi@Dell:/usr/src$ uname -a
Linux Dell 4.2.0-42-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 29 20:22:11 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ravi@Dell:/usr/src/linux-headers-4.2.0-42-generic$ sudo make oldconfig && make prepare
[sudo] password for ravi: 
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/bin2c
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
scripts/kconfig/conf  --oldconfig Kconfig
#
# configuration written to .config
#
arch/x86/Makefile:138: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
Makefile:662: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_REGULAR: -fstack-protector not supported by compiler
scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig

*** Error during update of the configuration.

make[2]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 1
make[1]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 2
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/entry/syscalls/../../include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h'.  Stop.
make: *** [archheaders] Error 2
```

Below is the other information-

```
VirtualBox Graphical User Interface
Version 5.0.24 r108355
Copyright © 2016 Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: I would call it a stretch to consider this a programming question.

Comment: @CharlieFish: LOL... I searched on SO and on Google too but couldn't find out any solution which worked for me. That's why, I put all the information on the question to make it clear.

Comment: Just because you searched and put all the information doesn't mean it should go on Stack Overflow. It's not a programming question. Stack Overflow is meant for programming questions.

Comment: @CharlieFish: FYI, please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13670176/1175065)

Comment: I would say the same thing to that person. Once again Stack Overflow is meant to be a programming website. Not a tech support site.

Comment: @CharlieFish: Ok. Noted down. Thanks. Since, I saw the similar question posted in SO, I posted here. Could you please redirect me to appropriate place?

Comment: I'd say probably Super User.

Comment: @RaviJoshi I'm glad you posted this even though it's out of place on SO. It appears the _very_ recent kernel 4.2.0-42-generic is not yet supported by any released VirtualBox version. My VBox installation was working before I ran this kernel update about 5 days ago and that's when my VBox broke. Either roll back to an earlier kernel or wait for an updated VirtualBox release which supports it.

Comment: For me, rolling back to 4.2.0-38-generic kernel and VirtualBox 5.0 worked. Next time, asking on http://askubuntu.com/ would be best. See http://askubuntu.com/a/700399/370910

Comment: @MikeAtlas: I really appreciate you. I was about to reinstall OS but thankfully I got another answer to [disable Secure Boot in BIOS settings](http://askubuntu.com/a/762255/569883). Thank you very much.

Comment: Reinstalling the OS isn't necessary to use an older kernel, but that other post is helpful. I'll switch back to my newer kernel and try it out. Thanks back.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030662/cant-install-virtualbox-in-arch/59536730#59536730) I posted, solved the issue for me without disabling Secure Boot mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you recently installed a new kernel version, try the earlier one. Kernel vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic doesnt work for me, but vmlinuz-4.2.0-41-generic works. Apparently, there is no vboxdrv version for vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic . I'm using VirtualBox 5.1.

Comment: Thank you very much. I disabled Secure Boot Option in BIOS settings. Please see [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/762255/569883).

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030662/cant-install-virtualbox-in-arch/59536730#59536730) I posted, solved the issue for me (without needing to disable Secure boot)